# How to call a javascript function from zend controller indexAction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-controller-router

i want to call a javascript function from zend controller indexAction. my controller is look like this..

// mycontroller.php

```
      public function indexAction(){
         $role = 'admin';
         $id = 23;
      // here i want to call the javascript function 
       /// like myjsfun(role, id);
       }
```

and viwefile for the controller is 
       //index.phtml

```
    here is my javascript function

   <script type='text/javascript'>

   function myjsfun(role, id){
    // code for this function
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

//mycontroller.php

```
$role = 'admin';
$id = 23;

$this->view->role = $role;
$this->view->id = $id;
```

//index.phtml

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function myjsfun(role, id){
        // code for this function
    }

    //actual call:
    myjsfun(<?php echo Zend_Json::encode($this->role) ?>, <?php echo Zend_Json::encode($this->id) ?>);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks.. Can i call the function within controller like <script type='text/javascript'>myjsfun(<?php echo role; ?>,<?php echo id; ?>);</script>

Comment: No. The syntax is incorrect (PHP variables need a `$`) and you don't have a variable `$role` nor `$id` in scope. What is wrong with the code I proposed?